# Text View not displaying (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, textview

So I'm having trouble getting a TextView to appear programmatically with Java. Here's the code:

```
LinearLayout layout=new LinearLayout(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.0F);
TextView tx = new TextView(this);
tx.setText("Hello World");
layout.addView(tx);
```

Comment: Have you set the dimensions for the textview ?

Comment: So are you adding Layout to your content view? Try calling `requestLayout()`

Comment: @user3839099 Please post your layout xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you ever setting the content view for the current activity?  The LinearLayout you're dynamically creating doesn't appear to ever be displayed.

Do something like this after you create it (or create the linear layout in your XML first, then dynamically add the text box):

```
setContentView(layout)
```

Comment: We're doing setContentView () in onCreate(), this is just a function to generate textviews when a button is pressed

Comment: So is there something wrong with our code? It's not adding to the current view